# Individual WebApps FTP Credentials

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to setup separate FTP access for each WebApp created.

In the portal, FTP information is provided, but that is based on a single user for all WebApps.  Changing it, changes it across all WebApps.

How do I create individual users with their own credentials?

Answer (score 0):

If you need separate credentials for each site, use the credentials from the publishing profile. If you need each user to have their own credentials, you can make them co-admins of your subscription.

The publish profile is an XML file that contains both WebDeploy and FTP related things. If you glance in there, you will easily locate the credentials. They look like:

```
Username: if your site is named 'MyCoolSite', the user name will be '$MyCoolSite'
Password: some long random string
```

Please see David Ebbo's page on deployment credentials for some more information:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials